# Powershell, comparing 2 files to find the amount of unique entries in both files

Tags: powershell

I have 2 files. The contents of

```
File 1 is: 4,22,1,2,3,14,12,13.
File 2 is: 1,50,2,12,3,6,9.
```

Im trying to write a script that outputs the total unique entries in both files and the `total unique numbers in file 1 and file 2`. I am currently using:

```
$howmany = compare-object $(get-content C:\test\file1.txt) $(get-content C:\test\file2.txt)
Write-Host "Total unique entries in both files is:" $howmany.Count
```

This does the total unique entries in both files but I can't figure out how to find the total unique entries in file 1 and file 2.

I want the output to be something like:

```
Total unique entries in file 1 is: 4
Total unique entries in file 2 is: 3
Unique numbers in file 1 are: 4 22 14 13
Unique numbers in file 2 are: 50 6 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the AsHashTable and AsString parameters to return the groups in a hash table, that is, as a collection of key-value pairs.

In the resulting hash table, each property value is a key, and the group elements are the values. Because each key is a property of the hash table object, you can use dot notation to display the values.

```
$unique = $howmany | Group-Object -Property sideindicator -AsHashTable  -AsString
```

File1
since the output is an array the `-join` operator is used to join each number to form a string

```
($unique.'<=' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject) -join ','
```

File2

```
($unique.'=>' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject) -join ','
```

File1 - Count unique items

```
($unique.'<=' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject).count
```

File2 - Count unique items

```
($unique.'=>' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject).count
```

Comment: Please improve the answer by explaining what's going on. Code-only answer doesn't explain the *what* and *why*, just *how*.

Comment: `$unique = $howmany | Group-Object -Property sideindicator -AsHashTable  -AsString`  What is this doing? Seems to work fine without this

Comment: the commands i have shown are all additional commands to what you already have.

Comment: Is there a way to put this into a foreach loop?

Comment: what is the requirement for the foreach loop...does the above not give you what you want?

Comment: It gives me The unique numbers eg: 4,22,14,13 for file 1 and file 2 but not how many unique entries there are in file 1 and file 2 eg: 4 for file 1 and 3 for file 2

Comment: okay that is easy just use `count` like you did in your code. see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

(I know you have an accepted answer, I just wanted to write an alternative. I can't make it work the way I was trying to approach it, but this is close).

```
function uniques {param($a,$b) $a|? {$b -notcontains $_}}

$f1 = (gc C:\test\file1.txt) | select -unique
$f2 = (gc C:\test\file2.txt) | select -unique

Write-Host "Total unique entries in both files is: $(($f1+$f2 |select -Unique).Count)"

Write-Host "Total unique entries in file 1 is: $((uniques $f1 $f2).Count)"
Write-Host "Total unique entries in file 2 is: $((uniques $f2 $f1).Count)"
Write-Host "Unique numbers in file 1 are: $(uniques $f1 $f2)"
Write-Host "Unique numbers in file 2 are: $(uniques $f2 $f1)"
```

NB. Your initial code, and therefore @Kiran's answer, has a bug if one of the files contains a duplicate number. e.g. if file1 contains `4,22,1,2,3,14,12,13,4` with a duplicate 4 in it, you'll get `5 unique numbers - 4,22,14,13,4`. That's why this has `|select -unique` for both files when reading them.

NB. my version might fail if a file has only one number, or there is only one unique number. `@()` around things to make sure they stay as arrays if that matters.